# how does echo work on a server in php?

Tags: php, server, echo

To make a long story short I am trying to retrieve the salt of user passwords from a database. The way I planned to do it is when someone attempts to log in, it will take their username and find a the salt saved for that account and the server will echo it. My question is what if multiple people try to login at the same time, will it echo back two salts in the same statement or is each echo separate to each user connecting?

Comment: Every request is processed in isolation.

Comment: Simple answer: *No*. For more information, you should look into how PHP is processed and how it fully works, look at it like a dynamic html creating language... I hope that helps.

Comment: the title doesn't reflect the question; IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are   using **Linux/Unix** and nginx  .

Remember first  that  **In Linux/UNIX, everything is a file**  .

The request will run like below :

**browser ->nginx->(FastCGI)->php-fpm  run the script ->(FastCGI)->nginx->browser**

When request arrive the nginx  , it will send them to php-fpm by  **FastCGI protocol**. the php-fpm work with master worker structure. There are many worker process,and the request will send to a worker process.

And when run "**echo  hello**" , it will compile to opcode [ECHO](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.echo.php) ，and the zendVM will  invoke  c function **write()** finally.

> ssize_t write (int fd, const void * buf, size_t count);

**In UNIX, everything is a file**  .
And socket is file too ,so it write to socket "**hello**"  finally.And the "hello" will response to  nginx .And the nginx will response to browser.

You do not have to worry that many request will get same message .

In [FastCGI Specification](http://www.mit.edu/~yandros/doc/specs/fcgi-spec.html)

> All data that flows over the transport connection is carried in
>   FastCGI records. FastCGI records accomplish two things. First, records
>   multiplex the transport connection between several independent FastCGI
>   requests. This multiplexing supports applications that are able to
>   process concurrent requests using event-driven or multi-threaded
>   programming techniques. Second, records provide several independent
>   data streams in each direction within a single request. This way, for
>   instance, both stdout and stderr data can pass over a single transport
>   connection from the application to the Web server, rather than
>   requiring separate connections.

And

> An application record contains information about **a particular reques**t,
>   identified by the **requestId** component.

Even if there are many request , the FastCGI protocol guarantee that each request will get different  requestId to identify each request.